# ID not being found in DOM when both create and destroy are AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm running into an issue where I allow my user to create an item, but they can also delete the item from the same page.

Currently when a user adds an item, it's added to the site through `create.js.erb` now I also add the ability to destroy the item. If they click on delete the method is deleted, however I'm not able to remove it from the site.

The reason is that if I run $('item-13') f.ex in my console, it's not found in the DOM because it was added through AJAX. So the issue I'm having is that in my `destroy.js.erb` I have:

```
$("#item-<%= @current_item %>").remove();
```

with my destroy action:

```
  def destroy
   @line_item = @cart.line_items.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
     format.js { @current_item = @line_item.id }
    end
  end
```

how can I make it so that I'm able to find the id I've attached to the div that displays the item when it's created?

After I reload the page I'm able to delete the div based on AJAX.

Comment: I don't think AJAX Is the issue - i think it's just that you've omitted the hash at the start of the selector:  `$('item-13')` should be  `$('#item-13')`

Comment: As you see in my destroy.js.erb the hash is there

Comment: Yes, that was a red herring/confusing example.  see my answer.

Comment: I think the problem is in your create.js.erb, would you post that file?

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery select will look at the CURRENT dom, ie it **will** include objects that have been added with Ajax.

I think the problem is that you have defined the block to handle the js request in the controller, in this line:

```
format.js { @current_item = @line_item.id }
```

This means that it **won't** go on to render `destroy.js.erb` - this is the default action if nothing else is defined.

I would fix this by moving everything into destroy.js.erb:

```
#controller
def destroy
 @line_item = @cart.line_items.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
   format.js 
  end
end

#destroy.js.erb
$("#item-<%= @line_item.id %>").remove();
```

Comment: this isn't working for me. There has to be some underlying issues. If I add an item, then go to the web console and type in $("#item-64").remove(); it still won't be removed. However if I refresh the page, it gets removed. If I look for #item-64 it returns:

j…y.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#item-76"}

Comment: What does `$("#item-64").size()` return?  If it's zero then it's not on the page.  Is the Ajax which adds the item definitely working?  Is it giving it the correct id?  Inspect the item (assuming it is there) and read it's ID.

Comment: It returns 0. I'm manually checking that the ID is in fact there on the site, and it is. As I said on refresh it returns 1. Could it be that the create.js.erb renders the cart div on creation? If I try to delete an item that was there before I refreshed the page it works perfectly.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with your create action.  What is the ID of the element that you have "manually checked" is on the page?